# Use infoBox from shinydashboard into shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm using `shiny` to build an App in my office, and I would like to use features like `infoBox` build in `shinydashboard`.

is it possible to use `infoBox()` into a `navbarPage` ?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(  
  navbarPage(title="my title",collapsible=T,
  tabPanel("Update",icon=icon("refresh","fa-2x",lib="font-awesome"),
            dashboardBody(
            fluidRow(infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card"))
             )))
```

I know it's certainly just a story of `css style` but i cant figured out how to do it.

here is how it look like in `shinydashboard` :
[image]

here is how it look like in my App using `shiny` :
[image]

And here is the `html` code made by `infoBox()` :

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="info-box bg-purple">
    <span class="info-box-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="info-box-content">
      <span class="info-box-text">Progress</span>
      <span class="info-box-number">25%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

can I make a css file to make my `shiny` output look like the `shinydashboard`  output ?

**## EDIT :**

Thank's to @Victorp and @MrFlick i have copy/paste all `css style` in link with box or infobox frome `shinydashboard.css` and adminLTE.css into my `boostrap.css` file and it work correctly. I can use my own css style and the infobox feature.

Comment: Can'y you just use the [shinydashboard css](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/blob/master/inst/shinydashboard.css)?

Comment: already try, it dosen't change anything. I put the  `shynidashboard css` into my `boostrap.css` file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hello you also need the `AdminLTE.css` file (you can find it in the `shinydashboard` dir) :

```
### ui
library("shiny")
fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Example of an infoBox with shiny"),
  # Add CSS files
  includeCSS(path = "AdminLTE.css"),
  includeCSS(path = "shinydashboard.css"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card"), fill = TRUE),
    infoBoxOutput("progressBox2"),
    infoBoxOutput("approvalBox2")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    # Clicking this will increment the progress amount
    box(width = 4, actionButton("count", "Increment progress"))
  )
)
### server
library("shiny")
function(input, output) {
  output$progressBox2 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
      "Progress", paste0(25 + input$count, "%"), icon = icon("list"),
      color = "purple", fill = TRUE
    )
  })
  output$approvalBox2 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
      "Approval", "80%", icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon"),
      color = "yellow", fill = TRUE
    )
  })
}
```

This app will work if you copy the files in your app directory, if you don't want to do that you can do :

```
# Function for adding dependencies
library("htmltools")
addDeps <- function(x) {
  if (getOption("shiny.minified", TRUE)) {
    adminLTE_js <- "app.min.js"
    adminLTE_css <- c("AdminLTE.min.css", "_all-skins.min.css")
  } else {
    adminLTE_js <- "app.js"
    adminLTE_css <- c("AdminLTE.css", "_all-skins.css")
  }

  dashboardDeps <- list(
    htmlDependency("AdminLTE", "2.0.6",
                   c(file = system.file("AdminLTE", package = "shinydashboard")),
                   script = adminLTE_js,
                   stylesheet = adminLTE_css
    ),
    htmlDependency("shinydashboard",
                   as.character(utils::packageVersion("shinydashboard")),
                   c(file = system.file(package = "shinydashboard")),
                   script = "shinydashboard.js",
                   stylesheet = "shinydashboard.css"
    )
  )

  shinydashboard:::appendDependencies(x, dashboardDeps)
}

library("shiny")
# ui 
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Example of an infoBox with shiny"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    infoBox("New Orders", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card"), fill = TRUE),
    infoBoxOutput("progressBox2"),
    infoBoxOutput("approvalBox2")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    # Clicking this will increment the progress amount
    box(width = 4, actionButton("count", "Increment progress"))
  )
)
# Attach dependencies
ui <- addDeps(
  tags$body(shiny::fluidPage(ui)
  )
)
# server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$progressBox2 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
      "Progress", paste0(25 + input$count, "%"), icon = icon("list"),
      color = "purple", fill = TRUE
    )
  })
  output$approvalBox2 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
      "Approval", "80%", icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon"),
      color = "yellow", fill = TRUE
    )
  })
}
# app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I recognize that this is a very old post.  Tried this answer but only the icon rendered.  No text or numbers

Comment: You can try `shinyWidgets::useShinydashboard` to do that, see https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/useShinydashboard.html